# The client certificate credentials were not recognized error when calling a web service from stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, networking, ssms, database-administration

I'm trying to call a web service from a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014, but I get this error

> The client certificate credentials were not recognized

This code is working as expected in SQL Server 2017 but throwing an error in SQL Server 2014. How can I resolve the issue in SQL Server 2014?

I have created a certificate in power shell and enabled OLE Automation.

```
--Creation of certificate
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "ServerXMLHTTP", "ServerXMLHTTP" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"

--SQL Code to invoke the web service from a stored procedure
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @password VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @obj INT
DECLARE @sUrl VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @response VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @hr INT
DECLARE @src VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @desc VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @status INT
DECLARE @statusText VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @postData NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @source VARBINARY(MAX),  
        @encoded_base64 VARCHAR(MAX),  
        @auth VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ret BIGINT

SET @username = 'suhas'
SET @password = '12345'

SET @source = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @username+':'+@password) 

-- Convert from varbinary to base64 string 
SET @encoded_base64 = CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable       
("@source"))', 'varchar(max)') 
SET @postData = '{"LeadDetails":{"LeadID":"3715089","Counter":"2"}}';   

 
SET @sUrl = 'https://someWebLink/suhas'


print @surl
print @postdata
print @encoded_base64
SET @auth = 'Basic ' + @encoded_base64
print @auth
exec @ret= sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.SERVERXMLhttp', @obj out
IF @ret <> 0     
BEGIN    
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @obj, @source OUT, @desc OUT    
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @ret),     
                  source = @source,     
                  description = @desc,     
                  FailPoint = 'Create failed',     
                  MedthodName = 'POST'     
      --goto destroy     
      return    
END    
print @ret--YES
exec @ret=sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Open', null, 'POST', @sUrl, false
IF @ret <> 0     
BEGIN    
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @obj, @source OUT, @desc OUT    
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @ret),     
                  source = @source,     
                  description = @desc,     
                  FailPoint = 'Create failed',     
                  MedthodName = 'POST'     
      --goto destroy     
      return    
END    
print @ret--YES
exec @ret=sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Authorization', @auth
IF @ret <> 0     
BEGIN    
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @obj, @source OUT, @desc OUT    
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @ret),     
                  source = @source,     
                  description = @desc,     
                  FailPoint = 'AUTHO failed',     
                  MedthodName = 'POST'     
      ---goto destroy     
      return    
END    
print @ret--YES
exec @ret=sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Accept', 'application/raw'
IF @ret <> 0     
BEGIN    
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @obj, @source OUT, @desc OUT    
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @ret),     
                  source = @source,     
                  description = @desc,     
                  FailPoint = 'PASSING CONTENT TYPE failed',     
                  MedthodName = 'POST'     
      --goto destroy     
      return    
END    
print @ret--YES
EXEC @ret =sp_OAMethod @OBJ,'setOption',NULL,3,'LOCAL_MACHINE\My\ServerXMLHTTP'
IF @ret <> 0     
BEGIN    
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @obj, @source OUT, @desc OUT    
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @ret),     
                  source = @source,     
                  description = @desc,     
                  FailPoint = 'CERTIFICATE PASSING failed',     
                  MedthodName = 'POST'     
      --goto destroy     
      return    
END    
print @ret
EXEC @ret= sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send' , NULL, @postData
IF @ret <> 0     
BEGIN    
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @obj, @source OUT, @desc OUT    
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @ret),     
                  source = @source,     
                  description = @desc,     
                  FailPoint = 'PASSING DATA failed',     
                  MedthodName = 'POST'     
    --  goto destroy     
      return    
END    
print @ret
exec @ret= sp_OAgetproperty @obj, 'responseText', @response out
print @ret 
print @response
exec @ret= sp_OAgetproperty @obj, 'Status', @status out
print @ret
exec @ret= sp_OAgetproperty @obj, 'StatusText', @statusText out
print @ret
exec sp_OADestroy @obj
 
select @status [StatusCode], @statusText [StatusText], @response [Response]

return
```

Comment: Are SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2017 installed on the same machine? If not there will be two different client certificates. They may have the same Common Name but they'll have different serial numbers, validity dates and thumbprints.

Comment: It is been installed on the same system.

Comment: Are SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2017 running under the same Windows account credentials? Possibly 2017 has read access to LOCAL_MACHINE\My and 2014 does not.

Comment: Shall we connect once? This is a bit urgent for me.

Comment: How can I check that?